# using apply() and max() functions together, why use "null" instead of "this"?

Tags: javascript, apply

why use "null" instead of "this"? I tried "this" and it works but in other questions in stack overflow and on mdn(mozilla developer network) it is used with "null". Here's an example.

```
 var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbersArray);
```

Comment: From that link: "But, max doesn't depend on the current context. So, anything would work in-place of Math/null."

Comment: `this` doesn't make sense (what does it refer to?). If anything, you should pass `Math`, but as it doesn't matter you just pass nothing.